# Accessing Spring Security User Details from within Mule Services

Tags: spring-security, mule

We're securing Mule services using the Spring Security Framework, and some of the services need to access some information in the UserDetails object.  Is there a way to access this object from within a Mule service?

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way for the service to access the UserDetails object in Spring Security and that's through the ThreadLocal `SecurityContextHolder()`.

Comment: It's been checked complete.  I tried to upvote it, but I haven't accumulated enough reputation points to do so.

Comment: Finally acquired enough reputation points to upvote the answer. :)